# Prevent building package-lock.json frequently

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have a `package.json` file where I have dependencies fixed to a particular version:

[image: package.json]

I had run `npm install` few days back and it generated the `package-lock.json` file. In the `package-lock.json` file, I can see that the exact version of `eslint`, i.e. `v8.23.1`, is installed but the sub-dependencies have a caret sign meaning it'll install the latest major/minor versions, e.g. `@eslint/eslintrc= "^1.3.2"`:

[image: package-lock.json]

[image: eslintrc_dep]

After pushing my code, when the Jenkins build runs, it fails saying:

[image: jenkins error]

This is because a new version of `@eslint/eslintrc` is available and my `package-lock.json` has mapping of `v1.3.2`. I have two options in mind:

1. Update `package-lock.json` every time a sub-dependency gets upgraded but I'll have to do it quite frequently.
2. Lock dependencies using `overrides` field in `package.json` but this will also have to be updated frequently.

I want to freeze the dependencies (which I already did as seen in `package.json`) and also the sub-dependecies, until I decide to update them manually.

What should be done in this case?

My Node version is v16.15.0 and NPM version is v8.5.5.

Comment: `npm ci` doesn't fail just because newer versions are available, the lock file would be totally pointless if that was the case. It's not clear how they've become out of sync, do you get changes when you install locally? But yes, your transitive dependencies will be ranges unless their authors also locked them to exact versions.

Comment: I'm not quite able to understand, why are you passing through all this complexity? Is it an operational problem or something stuck in the brain of NPM which you're unable to make it forget about it? Try to delete the `package-lock.json` file and `node_modules` directory completely, then run `npm i` again, NPM should handle all of that by itself, why is it called a package manager then?

Comment: @jonrsharpe When I run ```npm ci``` in local, everything runs fine and when I run ```npm i``` I do see ```@eslint/eslintrc: 1.3.3``` getting installed

Comment: And do you have any local changes? Is it the same NPM version locally and in Jenkins?

Comment: No, I do not have any changes but for jenkins we are using ```env.NODE_VERSION = '16 --lts'```.

I should probably try to use same version as my local i.e. ```v16.15.0``` on Jenkins as well.

Comment: The issue was with node version. After setting it to v16.15.0, it worked fine. Thanks @jonrsharpe :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the node version. Earlier `env.NODE_VERSION = '16 --lts'` was being used. After setting it to v16.15.0, it worked fine. Thanks, @jonrsharpe :)